# Generate object files in subdirectory using a Makefile

Tags: makefile, subdirectory

I am trying to create a Makefile in order to generate object files in a subdirectory rather than let them in the src/ folder.
Here is the structure of the project:

```
Trunk
- Server
  - src/
  - include/
- Common
  - src/
  - include/
```

The Makefile is located in `Trunk/Server`. Source files are located both in `Server/src` and `Common/src`, so the Makefile currently has something like this:

```
SRC        =        src/main.cpp                  \
                    src/Network.cpp               \
                    ../Common/src/SQLManager.cpp  \
                    ../Common/src/Utils.cpp
```

I woud like to put generated object files in respective `obj` folders, so  `Trunk/Server/obj` and `Trunk/Common/obj`. How can I achieve this? I've found many ways to generate object files in subdirectories (`vpath`, `patsubst` and many more) but I can't make any of them work for this folder organization.

Edit: If there is a way to put all object files in `Server/obj/`, that would be ok too.

Here's the complete Makefile (minus some source files and linked libraries):
Edit2: Updated with Didier Trosset's changes

```
CXX             =       g++

RM              =       rm -vf

NAME            =       Server

SRC             =       src/main.cpp                  \
                        src/Network.cpp               \
                        ../Common/src/SQLManager.cpp  \
                        ../Common/src/Utils.cpp

OBJ             =       $(subst src/,obj/, $(subst .cpp,.o, $(SRC)))

LDFLAGS         =       -lpthread -lm

CPPFLAGS        =       -std=c++0x -pedantic -Wextra -Wall -Wconversion -Iinclude -I../Common/include

all: Server

%.o: %.cpp
        $(CXX) $< -o $@

Server: $(OBJ)
        $(CXX) -o $(NAME) $(OBJ) $(LDFLAGS)

clean:
        $(RM) $(OBJ) *~

fclean: clean
        $(RM) $(NAME)

re: fclean Server

.PHONY: all clean fclean Server
```

Comment: A question like this gets asked here almost every other week. Did you try a search and if so can you explain why/how the answers to those questions don't work for you?

Comment: I did try to search, and read answers such as these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178125/gnu-make-how-to-get-object-files-in-separate-subdirectory , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231229/how-to-generate-a-makefile-with-source-in-sub-directories-using-just-one-makefil . But the folder structure isn't exactly the same and the Makefile usually doesn't work at all (can't find `.cpp`s, wrong command line...)

Comment: Another question: why do you think this question comes up so often, and why do you think the Makefile usually doesn't work at all? This scheme simply has inherent problems; pattern rules break down because of the need to prefix everything with the correct directory. To maintain your Makefile's and your own sanity, just don't do this. Stick to [Paul's third rule of Makefiles](http://mad-scientist.net/make/rules.html), or migrate to a more advanced build system.

Comment: My answer to that question: the insanity is in `make`'s peculiar handling of directories and directory separators.  It looks like it was designed to support rules operating on files all in the same directory with cross-directory support sort of hacked in afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given these definitions, `subst` should be used to substitute the `src` part of the directory, and the file extension.

```
OBJ = $(subst src/,bin/,$(subst .cpp,.o,$(SRC)))
```

Then, you have to add new pattern rules to compile your source files. (You have to write one pattern rule per directory where your source files are.)

```
obj/%.o: src/%.cpp
         $(CXX) -c $< -o $@

../Common/obj/%.o: ../Common/src/%.cpp
         $(CXX) -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: I tried that (after removing the extra comma after `subst`), and it seems to make GCC look for the `.cpp` files in `obj/` instead of `src/`... I got a `no rule to make target` error.

Comment: @Jukurrpa Thanks for the comma. Also, what is the rest of your Makefile. What you posted here is not enough! You need other targets, at least to link your objects.

Comment: Yes, I didn't specify the 'usual' rules such as the one calling `$(OBJ)` and then the linking of all objects. I can add them to my original post if that can help you finding a solution :)

Comment: @Jukurrpa Please post more of your Makefile. The error does not seem related to the `SRC` or `OBJ` now.

Comment: I added my 'original' Makefile. I replaced my `OBJ` with yours and added the `%.o` rule and immediately got `make: *** No rule to make target 'obj/main.cpp', needed by 'server'.`

Comment: First, you have to leave the `all` rule as the first rule. Second, you have to replace the `server` rule by the linking rule to create your target (the binary executable file).

Comment: Well, the `server` rule is the linking rule... Unless you mean removing `$(OBJ)` on its first line?

Comment: Then there's a mismatch between the `server` rule and the `Server` target name. You should use the same. Otherwise, as the rule creates `Server` and the Makefile expects `server` the link will always be done.

Comment: Also, I fixed my answer. The `OBJ` variable should also substitute the `.cpp` to `.o`. This will fix the error.

Comment: I added the `subst` (btw it seems that one shouldn't put a space after the first comma as make also adds it in the replacement), I now get a `no rule` error for `obj/main.o`. Getting closer?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7756/discussion-between-jukurrpa-and-didier-trosset)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this will work, but I would try something like:

```
OBJ := $(join $(addsuffix ../obj/,$(dir $(SRC))),$(notdir $(SRC))
# or, as Didier suggested:
# OBJ := $(subst src/,obj/,$(SRC))

%.o: ../src/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $< -o $@
```

Comment: I get the same error as with Didier Trosset's method. It makes GCC look for `.cpp` files in `obj/` folder.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly what you're trying to do, but this should come close:

```
OBJ = $(subst src/,obj/,$(SRC:.cpp=.o))

obj/%.o : src/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $< -o $@

../Common/obj/%.o : ../Common/src/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $< -o $@
```

Comment: I guess, you meant `%.cpp` instead of `*.cpp`, didn't you?

Comment: This works for the files located in `src/`, but not for the ones in `../Common/src`. I tried to change the path of source files and rule to `./src/` so there is no ambiguity between the two, but it didn't work.