# How to create targets into specific directory with make?

Tags: makefile, g++

My path:

./folder1/folder2/

My makefile is located in folder1.

My makefile:

```
CC = g++
FLAGS = -o3 -std=c++11

all: prng.o exec

prng.o: ./folder2/prng.cpp
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -o $@ $<

exec: prng.o
    /$<
```

prng.o is generated in folder1. I want it to be generated in folder2. How to do that?

Comment: This is unclear.  `foo.cpp` is a source file, it doesn't "create" anything.

Comment: sorry, I edited it

Comment: That still doesn't help - assuming you mean an actual executable (rather than an object file), then it's that executable's responsibility to write output to the correct location.

Comment: edited. better now?

Comment: Easy, just change the target from `prng.o` to `folder2/prng.o`. This question has been asked and answered many times in this forum.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate object files in subdirectory using a Makefile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260058/generate-object-files-in-subdirectory-using-a-makefile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CC = g++
FLAGS = -o3 -std=c++11

all: folder1/prng.o exec

folder1/prng.o: folder2/prng.cpp
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -o $@ $<

exec: prng.o
    /$<
```

BTW, your C compiler should have a C11 binary, something like `/usr/bin/c11`.  That would let you say,

```
CC = c11
CFLAGS = -o3
```

Also, by using CFLAGS (instead of FLAGS), you shouldn't have to mention it in the recipe.