# Makefile: rule to put .o in different directory

Tags: c++, makefile, directory-structure

I've got this directory structure:

- `./src` contains the the .`cpp` and the `.h` of all the files I need
- `./bin` should contain the `.o` temporarily and the `.bin` permanently. Also, this folder should be deleted when calling `make clean`.
- `./` contains the `Makefile`

This is my current `Makefile`:

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -pedantic -g
CC = g++
EXEC = flrfile
SRC_DIR = src
BIN_DIR = bin
OBJ = FixedLengthFieldsRecord.o FixedLengthRecordFile.o main.o

all: flrfile

../$(BIN_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)%.cpp $(SRC_DIR)%.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(SRC_DIR)%.cpp -o $@

$(EXEC): $(OBJ)
    @mkdir -p bin
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(BIN_DIR)/$(OBJ) -o $(BIN_DIR)/$(EXEC)

.PHONY : clean

clean:
    -rm -rf $(BIN_DIR)
```

When I run `make`, I get this error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `FixedLengthFieldsRecord.o', needed by `flrfile'.  Stop.
```

Why is this?

PS: Also, how could I make the `OBJ = FixedLengthFieldsRecord.o FixedLengthRecordFile.o main.o` more generic? I don't want to write all the `.o`...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178125/gnu-make-how-to-get-object-files-in-separate-subdirectory

Answer (score 3):

It's because you don't have a rule for `something.o`, you have a rule for `../bin/something.o`.

If you change your `OBJ` declaration to

```
OBJ = ../$(BIN_DIR)/FixedLengthFieldsRecord.o ../$(BIN_DIR)/FixedLengthRecordFile.o ../$(BIN_DIR)/main.o
```

It should work.

You could get objects from source dir using wildcards

```
SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
OBJ := $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%,%,$(SOURCES))
OBJ := $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(OBJ))
OBJ := $(addprefix ../$(BIN_DIR)/,$(OBJ))
```

What this does is that first it get a list of cpp files from `$(SRC_DIR)`, removes the path, then replaces all cpp suffixes for o and lastly add `../$(BIN_DIR)/' in front of each item.

Comment: Also, `$(BIN_DIR)/$(OBJ)` in `$(EXEC): $(OBJ)` should be changed to `$(OBJ)`.

Comment: @Akobold, I get this: `Makefile:6: *** unterminated call to function `addsuffix': missing `)'.  Stop.`

Comment: @i19: Indeed, I missed a few ')' - just fixed it :)

Comment: @Akobold, now I get a "missing separator" error :( on this line: `@mkdir -p bin`

Comment: @l19: just edited my answer :)

Comment: @Akobold I still get the same error :S

Comment: Ok, I solved it... I was using white spaces instead of tabs.