# Save object files in same makefile directory using depend

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I have this `makefile`

```
appname := fun

srcfiles := $(shell find .. -name "*.cpp")
headerfiles := $(shell find .. -name "*.hpp")
objects  := $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(srcfiles))


all: $(srcfiles) $(appname)

$(appname): $(objects)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(appname) $(objects) $(LDLIBS)

depend: .depend

.depend: $(srcfiles) $(headerfiles)
    rm -f ./.depend
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -MM $^>>./.depend;

clean:
    rm -f $(appname) $(objects)

dist-clean: clean
    rm -f *~ .depend

include .depend
```

Where the `makefile`'s parent directory contain all the code (`.hpp` and `.cpp` files). Unfortunately, the `.o` files are saved in the source code, while I want that they're saved in the same directory of the executable (and `makefile`). This is the same of `Default` in Eclipse CDT.

How can I modify `makefile` in order to do that?

PS: I found similar questions, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178125/how-to-place-object-files-in-separate-subdirectory) one, but none of them used `depend` for defining the `$(objects)` task (they're all in `%.o% form).

Answer (score 1):

When you set your `objects` variable you are simply taking the full pathname to the `.cpp` file and replacing the suffix with `.o`.  So if you have a file like `my/sub/dir/foo.cpp` then `objects` will contain the path `my/sub/dir/foo.o`.  So, of course when you write a rule `$(appname): $(objects)`, make is going to try to build the file `my/sub/dir/foo.o`.  If you want it to build just `foo.o` instead, then you have to strip off the path as well, not just replace the suffix:

```
objects := $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(notdir $(srcfiles)))
```

Now, of course, make will say it doesn't know how to build `foo.o`, because the default rules only know how to build a `.o` from a `.cpp`, not from a `.cpp` file stashed in `my/sub/dir`.

To make this work the simplest solution is to [use VPATH](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/General-Search.html) and you can construct the value for VPATH from the list of directories you got from `srcfiles`, like so:

```
VPATH := $(sort $(dir $(srcfiles)))
```

You might also consider using a better dependency generation solution, for example [the one described here](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/).