# g++ makefile error: *.o: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, makefile, g++

I have a file structure for a project like this:

```
Project Folder
|
->source
    |
    -->main.cpp
    -->frac.hpp
    -->frac.cpp
-> obj
    |Empty for now, but will store the .o files
```

Here is my makefile:

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = --std=c++11 -Wall
LFLAGS = --std=c++11
SRC = source
OBJ = obj

all: frac

frac: $(OBJ)/main.o $(OBJ)/frac.o
    g++ $(LFLAGS) -o frac $(OBJ)/main.o $(OBJ)/frac.o

$(OBJ)/main.o: $(SRC)/main.cpp $(SRC)/frac.hpp
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -c $(SRC)/main.cpp

$(OBJ)/frac.o: $(SRC)/frac.cpp $(SRC)/frac.hpp
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -c $(SRC)/frac.cpp
```

Now, when I run the command make frac

I get these errors:

```
g++ --std=c++11 -o frac obj/main.o obj/frac.o
g++: error: obj/main.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: obj/frac.o: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [frac] Error 4
```

Now the strange part about this to me is that after these errors, it still generates main.o and frac.o in the current directory. I then have to do mv *.o obj to move them all into the obj directory. I can then run make frac and this time it works and generates the executable. I understand that make is trying to use linking files that don't exist, so how can I get them generated with the first run of the command?

Thank you!

EDIT: I've looked at this thread [How to place object files in separate subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178125/how-to-place-object-files-in-separate-subdirectory)
But I am unclear on how to implement that solution. I can't just copy paste that directly into my makefile, and his is structured differently than mine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The target name (`$(OBJ)/main.o`) tells Make what to *expect,* but it doesn't tell the compiler what to *build.* The `-o` flag will tell g++ where to put the file it builds. So change these:

```
$(OBJ)/main.o: $(SRC)/main.cpp $(SRC)/frac.hpp
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -c $(SRC)/main.cpp

$(OBJ)/frac.o: $(SRC)/frac.cpp $(SRC)/frac.hpp
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -c $(SRC)/frac.cpp
```

to these:

```
$(OBJ)/main.o: $(SRC)/main.cpp $(SRC)/frac.hpp
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $(SRC)/main.cpp

$(OBJ)/frac.o: $(SRC)/frac.cpp $(SRC)/frac.hpp
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $(SRC)/frac.cpp
```

Then you can use another automatic variable to simplify these rules:

```
$(OBJ)/main.o: $(SRC)/main.cpp $(SRC)/frac.hpp
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

$(OBJ)/frac.o: $(SRC)/frac.cpp $(SRC)/frac.hpp
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

And then, if you want, since these rules are very similar, you can combine them into a static pattern rule:

```
$(OBJ)/main.o $(OBJ)/frac.o: $(OBJ)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.cpp $(SRC)/frac.hpp
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```