# Makefile : How to put all the .o file in a directory

Tags: c, makefile

I want to put all the .o file in a different directory.
He can create all the .o file but he can create the .exe file
My Makefile:

```
CC = gcc
SRC = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.o)
EXEC = exe
CFLAGS = -Wall -pedantic -std=c11 -g


all : $(EXEC)
%.o : %.c
    $(CC) -o prog/$@ -c $< $(CFLAGS)
$(EXEC) : $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ prog/$^ $(CFLAGS)

clean : rm -rf *.o
mrproper : clean rm -rf $(EXEC)
```

And there is the result in shell (Ubuntu):

```
gcc -o prog/a.o -c a.c -Wall -pedantic -std=c11 -g
gcc -o prog/b.o -c b.c -Wall -pedantic -std=c11 -g
gcc -o prog/main.o -c main.c -Wall -pedantic -std=c11 -g
gcc -o exe prog/a.o b.o main.o -Wall -pedantic -std=c11 -g
gcc: error: b.o: No file or directory
gcc: error: main.o: No file or directory
Makefile:13: recipe for target 'exe' failed
make: * [exe] Error 1
```

PS : a.c : print A , b.c : print B et main.c use a.c and b.c

Comment: answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178125/how-to-place-object-files-in-separate-subdirectory

Comment: Have you considered using CMake to generate your Makefile rather than building it the hard way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two issues:

1. Your `%.o` rule doesn't actually create `%.o` files.
2. `prog/$^` expands to `prog/a.o b.o main.o` because `$(OBJ)` is `a.o b.o main.o`.

I'd do it like this:

Instead of `OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.o)`, write

```
OBJ = $(SRC:%.c=prog/%.o)
```

The rule for object files then becomes

```
prog/%.o : %.c
        $(CC) -o $@ -c $< $(CFLAGS)
```

and the executable can be created with

```
$(EXEC) : $(OBJ)
        $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)
```

Finally, for sanity reasons your cleanup rules should probably be

```
clean :
        rm -rf prog/*.o
mrproper : clean
        rm -rf $(EXEC)
```